# OpenGL project, using tessellation on a polygon rendered car

Tags: opengl, polygon, tessellation

Ok so im seperating my problem up because i need a depthy answer cos im nooby with it and will fail if i have just a generalisation answer.

I have a car body which i originally drew using line_loop and have changed it to polygon so i can texture it. however it ignores the wheel arches like so.

[image: car wrong]

(ignore the texturing for now, i need to figure that one out another time ;) )

This is what my car looks like with line_loop

[image: car shape]

If the way to make the wheel arches with polygon makes it a smoother circle then even better :)

This is my current code, (ignore the texture stuff) I did start tessellation with a prod in that direction from an earlier question but not sure exactly how to use it and which coords to pass etc etc. Thanks for all your help!!

```
void drawBody(int textureindex)
{
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureLib[textureindex]);

GLUtesselator *tess = gluNewTess(); // create a tessellator
      if(!tess) return 0;  // failed to create tessellation object, return 0

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

glTexCoord2f(0.0F, 0.0F);
      glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(-0.97, 0.0);
      glVertex2f(-1.97f, 0.0f);
//wheel arch begin.
glTexCoord2f(-0.93, 0.3);
      glVertex2f(-1.93f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(-0.95, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-1.95f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.2, 0.6);
glVertex2f(-2.2f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.6, 0.6);
glVertex2f(-2.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.82, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-2.82f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.8, 0.3);
glVertex2f(-2.8f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(-1.78, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-2.78f, 0.0f);
//end wheel arch.
//Front of car.
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(-3.8f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.2);
glVertex2f(-3.7f, 0.2f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.4);
glVertex2f(-3.8f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.7);
glVertex2f(-2.8f, 0.7f);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.7);
glVertex2f(-2.4f, 0.7f);
//Windscreen.
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(-1.0f, 1.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
glVertex2f(0.5f, 1.05f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.8);
glVertex2f(2.3f, 0.8f);
//rear bumper.
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.5);
glVertex2f(2.15f, 0.5f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.3);
glVertex2f(2.15f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.3);
glVertex2f(2.35f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(2.0f, 0.0f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.83f, 0.0f);
//wheel arch begin.
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.3);
      glVertex2f(1.85f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.4);
      glVertex2f(1.86f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.6);
glVertex2f(1.6f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.6);
glVertex2f(1.2f, 0.6f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.4);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.4f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.3);
glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.3f);
glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
glVertex2f(1.05f, 0.0f);
//end wheel arch.
glEnd();
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Revised code for tessellation, (only attempted on one wheel arch so far and has had no affect).

```
    GLdouble car[7][2] = { {-1.93,0.3}, {-1.95,0.4}, {-2.2,0.6}, {-2.6,0.6}, {-2.82,0.4}, {-2.8,0.3}, {-2.78,0.0} };
    GLUtesselator *tess = gluNewTess(); // create a tessellator
gluTessBeginPolygon(tess, 0);  
gluTessBeginContour(tess);
{
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[0], car[0]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[1], car[1]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[2], car[2]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[3], car[3]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[4], car[4]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[5], car[5]);
    gluTessVertex(tess, car[6], car[6]);
}
gluTessEndContour(tess);
gluTessEndPolygon(tess);
```

Thanks for all your help, the final image looks like this:

[image: car finished]

Again thanks for all your help! Especially PeterT :)

Comment: The immediate mode : `glBegin(…); for(…){glVertex(…);} glEnd();`, it hurts. Please stop using that and use vertex arrays. Immediate mode is disregarded for over a decade and depreciated since OpenGL-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the tessellator at all. Feeding the coordinates to the tessellator will look something like this

```
    gluTessBeginContour(tess);
        :
        gluTessVertex(tess, v[i], v[i]);
        :
    gluTessEndContour(tess);
```

Read here and grab the examples http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html

Comment: do i feed all of the coords of the car or just the ones that make up the wheel arches??

Comment: @Mike I think they are just separate Contours. But, you seem to have plain 2D here and if the textures for the wheels are i.e. PNG with transparency a plain square could do.

Comment: ok so i tried this on one of the wheel arches... if you look back at the question i have edited the bottom with the code which doesnt seem to make any difference :/

Comment: @Mike don't forget to setup the callbacks for the tesselator and collect the draw instructions. The example I linked to collected them into a display list (`glNewList(id, GL_COMPILE)`) and later draw with `glCallList(listId1)`

Answer (score 1):

GL_POLYGON is used for drawing **convex** polygons. Your car is not convex, so you can't draw everything in one go (glBegin.. glEnd). Split car into multiple parts that have different primitive types. GL_POLYGON can't be used for everything.

You aren't even using your [tesselator](http://glprogramming.com/red/chapter11.html).

Bottom line is that your question is very basic. Before going further with OpenGL, finish "OpenGL red book", that covers pretty much all basic information. Version 1.1 is [available online for free](http://fly.cc.fer.hr/~unreal/theredbook/) in [several different places](http://glprogramming.com/red/index.html).